# How to have a script in the <head> add script at the end of the <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

A client is using Sharetribe which allows you add custom JS via admin, but only in the head. I want my script to load after jQuery, but jQuery is loaded at the end of the body. How can I write vanilla JS that adds my main script to the end once the doc loads?

I tried this:

```
<script>
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.src   = "http://cdn...";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    var script2 = document.createElement("script");
    script2.type  = "text/javascript";
    script2.text  = "$(SOME.CODE.HERE);"
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
</script>
```

But it gets executed before the document is finished loading (and in particular, before jQuery is available). The only thing I can think of is to set a timer, but that seems buggy.

Any advice?

Comment: can you not wrap your code in window.onload ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `DOMContentLoaded` event:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

  // Your code here
});
```

`DOMContentLoaded` is same as [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event of `jQuery`.

[**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: To any reader in doubt: the best practice is not to wait for the page to load to include some extra script, you should wrap this script in a DOMContentLoaded listener and load it initially.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your code to wait for the DOM to finish loading:

```
window.onload = function() {        
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    //....
}
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    //....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're waiting for jQuery to load, you can simply wrap your code within jQuery's [`$(document).ready()` method](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here.
});
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

I realise that you've mentioned that you want this in "vanilla" JS, but as you're waiting for jQuery to load anyway this seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @Tushar I did read that, but it seems pointless if OP is waiting for jQuery to load anyway. You may as well use code jQuery has already provided.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", since jQuery is added at the end of the page.

Comment: @PeterR you'll need to place that code *after* your jQuery file is added (either after it in the `head` element - where it's being loaded in - or anywhere in your document's `body`).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I understand that, that's the point of my question. The CMS is forcing me to put my custom code at the top of the head. The CMS adds jQuery by default at the end of the body. Hence my issue.

Comment: That particular detail was absent from your question, Peter; James's solution looks perfectly reasonable if we're not told that JQuery isn't loaded until the end of the document. I've added that to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

When the browser run your code in `<head>`, the `<body>` element didn't existed yet. So, `document.body` was `null`.

To create a script a the `<body>` element, use 'load' event of `document`, for example:

```
.............
document.addEventListener('load', function(event){
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   ...............
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}, false);
............
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(){}` is executed when your dom element render successfully.