# call java script function on page load in asp.net using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, latitude-longitude

I wants to  call java script function on page load in asp.net using c#, my code is,
Asp.net 
code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="lat_log_record.aspx.cs" Inherits="LAT_LOG.lat_log_record" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="getloc();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getloc() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    document.getElementById("<%=hfLat.ClientID %>").value = latitude;
                    document.getElementById("<%=hfLon.ClientID %>").value = longitude;
                    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: coords,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                        },
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    map = new google.maps.Map(
                        document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
                    );
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: coords,
                        map: map,
                        title: "Your current location!"
                    });

                });
            } else {
                alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
            }
        }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #mapContainer {
            height: 500px;
            width: 800px;
            border: 10px solid #eaeaea;
        }
        </style>
        <div id="mapContainer" runat="server" visible="false">
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLat" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLon" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="login" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvloc" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lbllat" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbllog" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace LAT_LOG
{
    public partial class lat_log_record : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Class1 ob = new Class1();
        List<Class1> lst = new List<Class1>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:getloc();", true);
            ob.lat = hfLat.Value;
            ob.log = hfLon.Value;
            lst.Add(ob);
            // lbllat.Text = latitude;
            // lbllog.Text = longitude;
            gvloc.DataSource = lst;
            gvloc.DataBind();
        }


        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

I wants to run that java script on page load but it shows only blank grid...
i tried other option like...
**, winodows.onload in script**
but its not working, need help
thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DOMContentLoaded` event:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    getloc();
    // ^^^^^
});
```

[**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773084/2025923

**EDIT**

You have nested function `getloc()` inside `a()`. This is the reason `getloc()` is not invoked. You can remove the `function a() {` and its closing bracket `}`.

Otherwise, use following code:

```
function a() {
    function getloc() {
        ...
    }
    getloc(); // call when `a` is called
}
```

**EDIT-2**

Remove `return` from the body `onload`

```
<body onload="getloc();">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yfpf3ksr/

Comment: @TGiri You can put this code anywhere on the page. In your case you can put this after `function a()`

Comment: i did as you instructed @Tushar but it still showing empty grid

Comment: @TGiri Is function being called? DId you check that?

Comment: yes,  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:getloc();", true); on pageload

Comment: @TGiri No need of this, just add the code as I've shown above.

Comment: @TGiri ADDED DEMO LINK IN ANSWER!

Comment: @TGiri The question you asked `call java script function on page load in asp.net using c#` which is answered. right? If the grid is not working, please create other question for the same

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, on asp page you are calling getloc() function inside body tag and this getloc() is inside the function a(), seems wrong. Remove call inside body tag and try , server side code might work properly.