# $(document).ready not firing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have a view, showed below, and I am trying to make a ajax call on page load. However, $(document).ready doesn't seem to be firing (or isn't being called). Not sure what the problem is, it is working fine on another page. The code is below.

**Code (This $(document).ready does not work)**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Programs";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="dashboard grey lighten-3" ng-controller="DashboardController">
<div class="row gutter-14">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header relative">
                <div class="card-title">Programs</div>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group" ng-init="(comments=[]).length=8;">
                <a class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="i in comments track by $index">
                    <div class="pull-left m-r-10">
                        <i class="icon-circle {{theme_colors[$index]}}-border v-super"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item-heading" id="programName"></div>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text" placeholder-p></p>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div id="TestDiv"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("!!!");
});
</script>
```

In the Layout of _Layout.cshtml,  $(document).ready is being called as well. Could that be causing a problem?

**Other ready in _Layout.cshtml (This code works fine)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        fnamePlace.innerHTML = Cookies.get("Name");
        userEmail.innerHTML = Cookies.get("Email");
});
<script>
```

This is just adding a `Welcome, whoever` to my main page.

Comment: Have you loaded `jQuery` on page?

Comment: Option to that would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/29773084/2025923

Comment: Open your console and check for errors

Comment: @Tushar Uhmmm, I am pretty sure I have. I know it is loaded on the shared page.

Comment: @tymeJV I have, there are none

Comment: Multiple calls of `$(document).ready` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What happens if you put `alert("before ready");` right before the `$(document).ready` line?

Comment: @Barmar if I do that, it goes off. Does this mean I don't need `$(document).ready`?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. I just wanted to make sure that the script at the bottom was being executed.

Comment: Also check that jQuery isn't loaded _twice_

Comment: @Jacob I double checked, it is only being loaded once.

Comment: You should post the other `ready` handler in case it's doing something that will break this one.

Comment: @Jacob Added my other `ready` handler above

Comment: Does the other ready handler work, or is that broken too?

Comment: @BenVisness The other `ready` handler works fine.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no reason it should be failing, especially if there are no errors. Could your dev console be filtering errors in some way so you're not seeing them?

Comment: Is that a typo in the question, or is the `<script>` element you posted closed incorrectly on your page as well?

Comment: Since you're using angular why not use angular for this.  Just move the contents of ```$(document).ready()``` to ```DashboardController``` and use a binding to display them on the page.  Without seeing the definition of ```fnamePlace``` it's hard to suggest anything else

Comment: Also, in case you have _other_ scripts that are hijacking things, I'd put a breakpoint on your `$(document).ready` line and step in. Maybe that will clarify what's going on. I'm not familiar with Angular, but might it be redefining `$`?

Comment: Alright, I will give some of those a try. Will post the answer as soon as I figure it out. Thanks all of your answers and help!

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a partial view?

Comment: what is in your console by console.log($);

Comment: @Tebc brings up a good point.  The event may already have ben fired by the time a partial view loads