# Why is my add eventListener of null?

Tags: javascript, events, null, position

My addEventListener returns as null on my google development tools, but I have no clue why.

```
var sx = document.getElementById('sx');        // Element to hold screenX
var sy = document.getElementById('sy');        // Element to hold screenY
var px = document.getElementById('px');        // Element to hold pageX
var py = document.getElementById('py');        // Element to hold pageY
var cx = document.getElementById('cx');        // Element to hold clientX
var cy = document.getElementById('cy');        // Element to hold clientY

function showPosition(event) {                 // Declare function
sx.value = event.screenX;                    // Update element with screenX
sy.value = event.screenY;                    // Update element with screenY
px.value = event.pageX;                      // Update element with pageX
py.value = event.pageY;                      // Update element with pageY
cx.value = event.clientX;                    // Update element with clientX
cy.value = event.clientY;                    // Update element with clientY
}

var el = document.getElementById('body');      // Get body Element
el.addEventListener('mousemove', showPosition, false); // Move updates  position
```

Comment: Maybe `DOMContentLoaded` http://stackoverflow.com/a/29773084/2025923

Comment: Your `addEventListener` "returns as null", or you get an error on that line that you can't call a method `addEventListener()` on a null object?

Comment: I figured that out a moment ago. Undid the closure

Answer (score 2):

do you have an element whose `id="body"` ?

a quicker way to get the body element

```
var x = document.body;
```